# What is the Reflection class for?

Tags: php, reflection

**I am familiar with the concept of reflection** (*emphasize for those who overlook the question*) and I know what `ReflectionClass`, `ReflectionMethod`, `ReflectionObject` etc. do.

But while looking at the PHP documentation, I stumbled upon the [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflection.php) class, which has no further documentation than:

> The reflection class.

This class has no constructor, does not have known subclasses, and is instantiable.

What's its purpose?

Comment: check here some nice explanation goo.gl/zUs5B

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Same comment as for Filip: you did not understand the question. Please read it again. I'm not asking what Reflection as a concept is for.

Comment: yes question was the purpose of it.

Comment: I meant your question was "What's its purpose?", so it easy words it will help you know about other classes just like mirror shows our face via the light reflection. Check this tutorial which will give u more clear idea. http://www.sitepoint.com/introspection-and-reflection-in-php/

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty You still don't get it I'm afraid. The first line of my question states that I know what most `Reflection*` classes are for, which implies that I'm familiar with the concept of reflection. It also states that I have been using these classes for some time. There is just **one** class in the reflection class family that I have never encountered before, and I can't find its purpose. *That* is the question: what is this `\Reflection` class for?

Comment: My understanding was that `Reflection` class is the root/base class for the other reflection methods

Comment: @CrayonViolent It's not, they all implement `Reflector`, but none of them extends `Reflection`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears this class exists specifically for its `export()` method, *without* implementing the `Reflector` interface.

From [PHP 5 Recipes](http://books.google.com/books?id=-E7_x1uW-GgC&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71) (found with [a slightly annoying Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+"Reflection+class"+-ReflectionClass)):

> `Reflection`: This class implements as a static method the `export()` method defined by `Reflector`, although it does not actually implement the `Reflector` interface. You can use this method to dump all the methods and/or properties of a class, extension, property, method or parameter.

Comment: Now that's an answer. Thank you!